# Socket.io Extra Placeholder Frame being sent

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, network-programming

The following code results in a mysterious third frame:
`451-["clientMsg",{"_placeholder":true,"num":0}]`

### Cient

```
function sendMessage() {
    var bufArr = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(bufArr);
    bufView[0]=6;
    bufView[1]=7;
    bufView[2]=8;
    bufView[3]=9;

    // send binary message to server
    socket.emit('serverMsg', bufArr);
}
sendMessage();
```

### Server

```
socket.on('serverMsg', function (bufArr) {
    var ba = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var bv = new Uint8Array(ba);
    bv[0]=10;
    bv[1]=11;
    bv[2]=12;
    bv[3]=13;

    var bufView = new Uint8Array(bufArr);
    console.log("Data: ", bufView[0], bufView[1], bufView[2], bufView[3]);

    // Send message back to client
    socket.emit("clientMsg", ba);
});
```

### Client

```
socket.on('clientMsg', function (bufArr) {
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(bufArr);
    console.log("Data: ", bufView[0], bufView[1], bufView[2], bufView[3])
});
```

The above code is resulting in THREE frames I would expect only TWO frames, one from the client to the server and one from the server to the client.  Can anyone explain what this third frame is, and how to get rid of it?  See the blow screenshot:

[image]

Comment: any progress on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through socket.io's code, it looks like any time there is an object with binary data, it will replace that portion of the object with this placeholder event. It then sends the binary data in the order of the provided 'num' field, which it reconstructs on the client side.

Since you only have a single object you are sending out for the event 'clientMsg', it sends out the event with the placeholder object as the entire body, with a followup of the binary data.

See socket.io-parser's binary.js: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-parser/blob/master/binary.js - specifically the `_deconstructPacket` and `_reconstructPacket` functions.

I unfortunately also realized the overhead of adding binary is pretty rough, and I can't find much documentation other than the code.

Comment: Yes, this is how socket.IO maps a binary message to the on(message) event on the server.  This was to much overhead for us so we switched to WebSocket (ws) on the server and native websocket on the client.  We also use schemapack to send binary data which makes encoding and decoding and routing very easy for binary messages: https://www.npmjs.com/package/schemapack

Comment: Interesting @JaredSprague we defaulted to using msgpack-lite because of the ease of integration, but I'll check out schemapack now, thanks. As for reducing overhead, we are investigating webrtc http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/ due to the possibility of udp-style unreliable messaging in the browser