# Minimizing data sent over network (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, socket.io, arraybuffer

Hey there stackoverflow :)

I am building a fairly simple network game with node-js and socket.io.
I have tried to minimize the bytes send over the network by using ArrayBuffers which is working great so far. But I have noticed one thing which I am not understanding.

If i am sending a package from the client to the server using ArrayBuffers I am using 5 Bytes per package but socket.io directly sends another package afterwards with around 50 Bytes. I have analyzed the data sent over the socket on agar.io for example and they are just sending around 13 Bytes per package and nothing more. Has this to do with socket.io ?

The second package in my case carries the topic. So what am I missing ?

Code to test:

//Server

```
let IO = require("socket.io");
let http = require("http");

let server = http.createServer();

let io= IO(server);

io.on("connection", (s) => {
    console.log("connection");

    s.on("test", () => {
        console.log();
    })
})

server.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("running");
});
```

//Client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

<script>
    let socket = io("http://localhost");
    let arrBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(2); //2 is used here because in my game I just need 2 bytes per tick


    setInterval(() => {
        socket.emit("test", {test: arrBuffer});
    }, 500);
</script>
</html>
```

Networking tab of the test: (where you see the second package after every 3 Byte package)
[image]

Networking tab on agar.io (where there are just 13 Bytes uploads and nothing more)
[image]

Thanks for every help in advance.

Comment: It appears to be the nature of socket.io, as previously examined here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399101/socket-io-extra-placeholder-frame-being-sent)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `ws` package to send serialized array buffers and no extra bytes are sent. Want to try swapping the implementation and see if the payload is reduced?

https://github.com/websockets/ws